# how can use notepad++ in my project

Tags: c#, php, notepad++

i have some PHP code that saved in database.
i want write a program that read php from database and then load in notepad++ and after edit save to database.

it is possible use notepad++ in our php project as editor?

or it is possible load notepad++ to our c# project and use as editor?

**question:**
how can load notepad++ to (c# or php) project as editor?

Comment: You have php code in your database? Why?

Comment: yes,all code of my project saved in data base!i use processmaker and processmaker save code as trigger in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you could first save your PHP code to a temporary file in C:\temp\ (or somewhere you specify)

Then

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", @"C:\temp\tmpfile.php");
```

(I'm guessing at the file path names, change as appropriate)

Then as Võ Quang Hòa says use the `FileSystemWatcher` class to watch for the file to be saved, and when it is, your program will read it and save it back to the DB.

```
FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\temp\");
fsw.Filter = "tmpfile.php";
fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Changed);
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

and add function

```
private static void fsw_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
{
   // Code to save file to DB and delete temp file.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As my understand about your question (maybe wrong)
1. From your program, when click on a file, you call notepad++ by using this command

```
<Path to your notepad++> -n<line>  <Path to your source code file>
```

2. Detect the change or file by using this class FileSystemWatcher  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx